# Customize Change Spaces Shortcut in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, spaces

I have a Logitech mouse that is supposedly "unsupported", but I'd like to be able to click the mouse wheel left and right to switch spaces left and right. I figured out that Mountain Lion is interpreting these clicks as `control + page up` (click mouse wheel left) and `control + page down` (click mouse wheel right), because my IDE (Eclipse) switches text editor tabs when I click left and right. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2332440).

How can I map <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>page up</kbd> / <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>page down</kbd> to change spaces left and right?

There isn't a clear way to do this in System Preferences. I'm comfortable doing some `defaults writes` from Terminal, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722) to achieve it?

Comment: Nope. I hadn't heard of it, but it is exactly what I was looking for!